# TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource. Got this while fetching data from nodejs server

Tags: node.js, express, post, cors, axios

I am trying to fetch data in my react app from node js app and I got the error message given below:

**App.js** in react

```
    const url = "https://localhost:3001?address="+this.state.location ;
    fetch(url , {
      mode: 'no-cors' // 'cors' by default
    }).then((response)=>{
        response.json().then((data)=>{
            if(data.error)
            {
              this.setState({
                error : data.error
              });
            }
            else
            {
                this.setState({
                  temperature : data.temperature
                });
            }
        })
    })
```

**app.js** in node app

```
app.get('/weather' , (req , res)=>{
    if(!req.query.address){
        return res.send({
            error : 'Please, provide an address'
        })
    }
    geoCode(req.query.address , (error , {longitude , latitude , place}={})=>{
        if(error)
        {
            return res.send({
                error
            })
        }
        getWeather (latitude  ,longitude , (error , {temperature , humidity})=>{
            if(error)
            {
                return res.send({
                   error
                })
            }

            return res.send({
                temperature ,
                humidity ,
                place
            })


        })
    })

})
```

**Error Message:**
TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `https` url for a local hosted app. Unless you have provided certificates etc, it wouldn't work. You need to use `http://localhost:3001`

Comment: Thanks for that. Now i got an error like :

`SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data`

Comment: where do you have `json.parse` in your code as I can't see it.

Comment: I don't have it anywhere.

Comment: try to log what is coming in `response`. probably `response.json()` is giving the error.

Comment: @SBofficial You’re getting that *“unexpected end of data”* message because you’ve specified 'no-cors' mode.